# Hyphen escape in mhchem not working with bidi

Tags: mhchem, bidi

Typesetting my chemistry thesis using `mhchem`, I make semi-frequent use of the option to escape to text mode using `{}`, especially to typeset hyphens in the midst of chemistry like in the following way: `\ce{6{-}Me}`. The output should be:

> 6-Me

However, after the addition of a word in Hebrew, this broke. The new output is:

> 6 Me-

Is there any way I can fix this?

My version of the `mhchem` package is 4.04, distributed *via* TexLive, Ubuntu software sources. A minimal working example is attached. I’m using XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true,spelling=new]{german}

\setotherlanguage{hebrew} % <-- comment out this line for correct output.

\begin{document}
\ce{6{-}Me}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your example and it works as expected, both with and without `\setotherlanguage{hebrew}`. What LaTeX engine do you use?

Comment: @EricDomenjoud Funny, I forgot to mention it. XeLaTeX

Comment: `This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2016.9.27)`

Comment: I use XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016) and in both cases, I get 6-Me. However, I get a warning from polyglossia which says "No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `Hebrew'. I will use \language=\l@nohyphenation instead".Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: @EricDomenjoud Just to confirm: You are using version 4.04 of `mhchem`, too? Since the current one on CTAN is 4.05.

Comment: No, I'm using version 4.05: Package: mhchem 2016/08/07 v4.05

Comment: @EricDomenjoud Testing revealed that updating `bidi` was required and made things work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating `mhchem` to the newest version had no effect.

However, updating `bidi` put the hyphen back into the correct position. My former `bidi` was 19.something, the current version is 20.something.